# why strcat works weird in loop?

Tags: c, loops, strcat

I wanna have characters 'ab' for each element in a table, but in console I have this:

```
tab[0] = argvab
tab[1] = argvabab
tab[2] = argvababab
tab[3] = argvabababab
```

This is a part of my code:

```
char **tab = (char**)malloc((n) * sizeof(char*));
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    tab[i] = argv[1];
    strcat(tab[i], "ab");
    printf("tab[%d] = %s\n", i, tab[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tab[i] = argv[1];
strcat(tab[i], "ab");
```

You're not allowed to append things to the `argv` strings. They're fixed size blocks with no extra space. Appending invokes undefined behavior.

Also even if you could you'd be appending to `argv[1]` each time rather than `argv[i]`.

**Solution:** (a) Change `argv[1]` to `argv[i]`, and (b) copy each argument before you append to it.